# Closing a Client thread gracefully

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am troubleshooting a Delphi 7 Indy9 polling client.  I have tried adding a TEvent with a `waitforsingleobject` and many other ways to disconnect gracefully.  The error occurs in the readln. The error is usually an 'EIDConnection...not connected'. I have put a watch on it and the thread terminates. but the 'while' doesn't reevaluate the condition until the connection receives a msg from the server, so it just grinds at the `readln` until it receives a msg. So sometimes it disconnects gracefully but most times crashes. Is there a way to do this or do I just put a try...except around the readln and carry on...thanks in advance

```
procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
begin
    while not Terminated and FConn.Connected do
    begin
        // read msg from server
        Msg := FConn.ReadLn;
        Synchronize(ReceiveLine); 
    end;
end;
```

Comment: what is the actual problem?  If the connection is closed, `ReadLn()` is *supposed* to raise an exception, by design.  Remove the call to `Connected()` and let `ReadLn()` do its work. If you let the exception terminate the thread (which would be the correct thing to do), the `while` is *not* supposed to keep running since the exception jumps out of the loop.  So I don't understand what you are having trouble with exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some code to handle the Disconnect event. I had a similar problem to what you describe, and here's what I did (in this example, tcpServer is an instance of TIdTCPServer):

```
    procedure TformRemoteControlWnd.tcpServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    (*
    Connection is disconnected. Be careful, because this also gets called when
    the app is shutting down while a connection is active, in which case
    tcpServer may be gone already.
    *)
    begin
      if not Application.Terminated and Assigned(tcpServer) then
      begin
        sbarStatus.SimpleText := 'TCP/IP Disconnected';
        tcpServer.Tag := 0; // used to prevent rentrancy
      end;

      // shut down connection to stop thread from calling OnExecute event
      try
        AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
      except
        Sleep(0);
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: once the `OnDisconnect` event has been fired for a connection, the `OnExecute` event will not be fired again for that connection. Once the `OnDisconnect` handler exits, the connection will be closed.  There is no need to call `Disconnect()` in the `OnDisconnect` event handler.

Comment: Remy - Thanks, I give that a try. It was a while ago, but I seem to remember there was a reason I had to put the Disconnect() call in there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer...`Readln` will wait indefinitely until it receives a carriage return. So the Thread sits at `Readln` until the server sends a message or the socket is disconnected (which causes the crash).  In the Delphi compiler code, a comment was written in the `OnDisconnect` to trap the error using a `try...except`. So I just need to be careful to clean up before disconnecting the socket.  I thought I could find a cleaner close method.  Thanks for all the help.